# hashtag link is going to the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, scroll, hashtag

I am building a site that is mostly on one page (home page). I am using hashtags in the main navigation to take the user to the respective section on the page. All works fine on the main page but when you go to one of the external pages, then go back to the home page, instead of landing on the respective section the page scrolls all the way to the bottom.

The site is a custom Wordpress theme (responsive) with boilerplate and I am using the flexslider jquery plugin. I have narrowed the cause of the scroll/hashtag issue to the slider. Everything works just fine when I take out the slider, however I would like to keep the slider.

The slider is currently on the page, the site is at: http://mtnstd.970design.com. You will see the slider in the about section of the page. If you visit one of the menu pages or any external page, then go back to the home page by clicking one the main navigation buttons. You will see that the page goes to the bottom. I have seen the issue in Chrome, Safari, IE (7,8,9). In Firefox the page actually goes to the top, even without the slider in the page.

HTML is valid and I have tried disabling all wp plugins, disabled my custom js and js plugins (except the flexslider) as well as disabled all stylesheets. No luck...

Answer (score 0):

I've poked around at the JS, but nothing seems broken. Most of the JS is put into one line, which makes troubleshooting very difficult. Have you considered just using another JQuery slider plugin?

At work (A local place) we use a plugin called "VSlider" a lot, and it works just fine. Perhaps you could implement this instead of that "flexslider" plugin.

An example of the slider in use can be found here:
http://seward.com/visit-seward/ (Our Featured Members)

It may take the slider a few seconds to load since the images are quiet large and the graphics designer doesn't care about image size (ugh).

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, that is why i'm so stumped with this. All js is working with no errors and my HTML is valid so it's been hard to pinpoint the cause of the issue.

I looked at Vslider is it only a wp plugin? If I'm goona try another slider I would rather use one thats a jquery plugin as I try to limit the number of wp plugins I use.

Comment: UPDATE: you will not be able to see the site as I am making it live today. I will also be removing the slider so that the hashtags work correctly. hopefully some suggestions or recommendations will be possible still without the slider in the page.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; work and all that. Anyway, if I'm reading your question correctly, it uses the [coinslider](http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/) lib, which I'm sure you can put on your server and use without adding another WordPress plugin. HOpe everything goes well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

It was caused by the Google Translate-script that was hidden in a div: display:none;
+ attached with analytics.

When removing these two functions, the problem was resolved.